# segmentation fault while using two different stack of same class in a program

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, segmentation-fault, stack

i just started c++ and coded a program to push and pop in 2 stacks simultaneously inn a program....i coded it corectly but while i run the program and try to access the first stack i.e s1 it shows segmentation fault but i am able access my second stack s2 very perfectly.....help me

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 10
class stack
{
private:
    int arr[max],top;
public:
    void init()
    {
        int top=0;
    }
    void push(int a)
    {
        arr[top++]=a;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        return arr[--top];
    }
    int isempty()
    {
        if(top==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int isfull()
    {
        if(top==max)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int a,z,cas;
    stack s1;
    stack s2;
    s1.init();
    s2.init();
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter your choice i.e. :\n";
        cout<<"1.Pushing in stack s1.\n";
        cout<<"2.Pushing in stack s2.\n";
        cout<<"3.Poping from stack s1.\n";
        cout<<"4.Poping from stack s2.\n";
        cout<<"5.To STOP.\n";
        cin>>cas;
        switch(cas)
        {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Enter the number to push in stack s1:\n";
            cin>>a;
            if(s1.isfull()==0)
                s1.push(a);
            else
                cout<<"The Stack is full.\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Enter the number to push in stack s2:\n";
            cin>>a;
            if(s2.isfull()==0)
                s2.push(a);
            else
                cout<<"The Stack is full.\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            if(s1.isempty()==0)
                cout<<"The number poped out is :\n"<<s1.pop()<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"The stack is empty.\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            if(s2.isempty()==0)
                cout<<"The number poped out is :\n"<<s2.pop()<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"The stack is empty.\n";
            break;
        case 5:
            cout<<"The elements in stack s1 are :\n";
            while(!s1.isempty())
                cout<<s1.pop()<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"The elements in stack s2 are :\n";
            while(!s2.isempty())
                cout<<s2.pop()<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you "just started C++", you should invest time in using a debugger.  A debugger allows you to execute each statement one at a time (a.k.a single stepping) and see values of variables.

Comment: Since you are using C++, use the `bool` type with `true` and `false` values.  Using 1 and 0 is an ancient practice (like around 1960's or earlier).

Comment: You can simplify some of your functions by placing the comparison into a `return` statement, such as `return (top == max);`.

Comment: Also, rename your `stack` as `std::stack` is already in use and you have allowed every symbol from the `std` namespace by `using namespace std;`.

Comment: In your `push` method, you need to check for stack full before pushing an element.  Otherwise, you are accessing beyond the array, which causes *Undefined Behavior* (anything could happen).  Similarly, you need to check for stack empty before popping elements.

Comment: `init`, manually called, for a C++ class ?

Comment: If you use the `bool` data type, you don't need to perform "`==0`" in your `if` statements.

Comment: A good practice is to declare (define) variables close to where you use them.  So, you can define `a` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Prefer not to use the `exit` function, break out of the loop and return from the main function.  Or change the loop to check for an exit condition instead of looping forever.

Comment: "i coded it corectly but [...] it shows segmentation fault" – Those statements can't both be true at the same time.

Comment: `push` and `pop` allow to go out of bounds on the array.

Comment: "i coded it corectly but [...] it shows segmentation fault" – sorry for that....but i am getting segmentation fault now also....what should i do...

Comment: Find the error with the debugging software that came with your development environment and and fix the error.

Comment: thats not helpful in any sort of way...@user4581301

Comment: Regardless, it's what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more useful than a debugger is the art of reading carefully:

```
void init()
{
    int top=0;
}
```

declares a local variable `top`.

The member variable is left uninitialised, leading to Undefined Behaviour.
That one of the stacks appears to work is just bad luck.

Making it a proper assignment:

```
void init()
{
    top=0;
}
```

would do it, but this is C++, so you should use a constructor:

```
class stack
{
public:
    stack();
// ...
};

stack::stack()
    : top(0)
{

}
```

and then

```
stack s1;
stack s2;
while(1)
{
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help